# Resharper can't find master file outside of project

Tags: resharper

In my .aspx files, I have Page directives like:

```
<% Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" >
```

These pages are located in several projects. The `Main.master` page is located at the root of my website but it is outside of projects.

It seems that Resharper thinks the tilde (~) refers to the root of the project, not the root of the website.  As a result, when I hover over "~/Main.master", I see an error that the path is not found.  In addition all the `ContentPlaceHolderID` attribute values show up as errors in ReSharper (`cannot resolve symbol`).

Can I tell ReSharper where the real root is?

Answer (score 1):

Why not include that master page in each project? At least, as linked file.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't help... ReSharper still doesn't find it